# Unable to locate to the right version of python on Mac

Tags: python, macos, rpython

The big picture:

I am trying to let `rPython` package run python scripts that have packages such as `numpy`, `scipy`, and `scikit-learn`.

Now, if that is an impossible task, please let me know right away, because I have spent over 10 hours on this problem (finally switched to a Mac so rPython is installable and runs the most basic python script). But I am new to iOS.

The Question:

After switching to a Mac, I installed rPython and the latest R, RStudio and Anaconda 2. It turned out that Mac has another version of python installed on it.

I tried the following script to change the directory to the python from Anaconda 2:

```
library(rPython)

Sys.setenv(PATH = paste("/Usr/local/bin", Sys.getenv("PATH"), sep=":"))
```

But it still is showing the older version of python.

I also checked the version and path of the Anaconda 2 python with `which python` in the `terminal` and got the following output:

```
Last login: Fri Mar 10 11:23:19 on console

Yangs-MacBook-Pro:~ yanghuang$ which python

/Users/yanghuang/anaconda/bin/python

Yangs-MacBook-Pro:~ yanghuang$ python

Python 2.7.13 |Anaconda 4.3.1 (x86_64)| (default, Dec 20 2016, 23:05:08) 

[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I don't misunderstand your meaning you should use this script:

```
library(rPython)

Sys.setenv(PATH = paste("/Users/yanghuang/anaconda/bin/python", Sys.getenv("PATH"), sep=":"))
```

Also you can run this command in **Rstudio**:

```
> Sys.setenv(PATH = paste("/Users/yanghuang/anaconda/bin/python", Sys.getenv("PATH"),sep=":"))

> system("python --version")
Python 2.7.13
```

Another way:

```
sudo find /usr -name "*Rprofile*" -print
```

Find the Rprofile file and add this line then restart R:

```
.Internal(Sys.setenv("PATH", paste("/Users/yanghuang/anaconda/bin/python", Sys.getenv("PATH"), sep=":")))
```